# How can I compute the total space used by figures?

Tags: floats, measure

I'm finishing my Ph. D. thesis, and I need to specify some technical characteristics of the thesis including the cumulative space used by all figures (measured in pages). Is there any magic function that can tell me this number of pages? Or should I measure it by eye?

Comment: Probably you can use the `endfloat` package to place all figures at the end of the document and then count the pages that are occupied by the figures?

Comment: How did the previous PhD candidates address this requirement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works by patching the `\end@float` command used by figure etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newlength{\sumfloatht}
\setlength{\sumfloatht}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\end@float}{\@endfloatbox}{\@endfloatbox
  \global\advance\sumfloatht by \ht\@currbox}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{\pgfmathdivide{\sumfloatht}{\textheight}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\pgfmathresult}%
  \label{totalpages}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\totalpages}{\pgfmathdivide{\sumfloatht}{\textheight}%
  \pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\ref{totalpages} pages.

\begin{figure}[t]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[bp]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
\end{figure}

{\the\sumfloatht} total height.

{\totalpages} pages.

\end{document}
```

---

This version distinguishes between figure and tables.  To add algorithm floats (for example} just create a `\sumalgorithmht` length and add `\label` etc. to`\AtEndDocument`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newlength{\sumfigureht}\setlength{\sumfigureht}{0pt}
\newlength{\sumtableht}\setlength{\sumtableht}{0pt}
\newlength{\sumfloatht}\setlength{\sumfloatht}{0pt}% anything else

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\end@float}{\@endfloatbox}{\@endfloatbox
  \@ifundefined{sum\@captype ht}{\global\advance\sumfloatht by \ht\@currbox}%
    {\global\expandafter\advance\csname sum\@captype ht\endcsname by \ht\@currbox}%
}{}{}

\AtEndDocument{\pgfmathdivide{\sumfigureht}{\textheight}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\pgfmathresult}%
  \label{figurepages}%
  \pgfmathdivide{\sumtableht}{\textheight}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\pgfmathresult}%
  \label{tablepages}%
  \pgfmathdivide{\sumfloatht}{\textheight}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\pgfmathresult}%
  \label{floatpages}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ref{figurepages} figure pages.

\ref{tablepages} table pages.

\ref{floatpages} anything else.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.3\textheight}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OP, *please* add this to the template for theses at your school. Generations will prise your name...

Answer (score 4):

Please give all thanks to John Kormylo for the provided solution! I just show a handy workaround to include this value in any place of the document using `totcount` package (needs two runs).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{totcount}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newlength{\sumfloatheight@new}%
    \patchcmd{\end@float}{\@endfloatbox}{\@endfloatbox \global\advance\sumfloatheight@new by \ht\@currbox}{}{}%
    \newtotcounter{sumfloatheight@old}%
    \newlength{\sumfloatheight@old}%
    \setlength{\sumfloatheight@old}{\totvalue{sumfloatheight@old}sp}%
    \newcommand{\totalfigurepages}{\pgfmathdivide{\sumfloatheight@old}{\textheight}\pgfmathresult}%
}%
\AtEndDocument{%
    \setcounter{sumfloatheight@old}{\sumfloatheight@new}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\totalfigurepages{} pages.

\begin{figure}[t]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[bp]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
\end{figure}

\totalfigurepages{} pages.

\end{document}
```